# Backbone js bind method on collection

Tags: backbone.js

I am following the tutorial at:

http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/3.html

This is a piece of code I am stuck on:

```
 initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem', 'appendItem'); // remember: every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

      this.collection = new List();
      this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem); // collection event binder

      this.counter = 0;
      this.render();
    },
```

The line of code that I am having a hard time understanding is:

`this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem);`

I know there is a bind method in underscore, but I don't think that is the same bind function.

Could you explain what the above line is for and where I can read more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In backbonejs, a collection can trigger events. Example:

```
this.collection.trigger('myEvent');
```

In addition, you can also bind a collection to some events. Example:

```
this.collection.bind('myEvent', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Backbone.Collection.bind() method comes from Backbone.Events. Note that Backbone.Collection has all the methods of Backbone.Events mixed in (like all the other backbone.js objects including Backbone itself).
2. Backbone.Events.bind() is an alias for Backbone.Events.on().